# Retrofit lockout for a suspension fork?

Tags: brakes, fork, suspension, hybrid-bike

I am new for cycling. I am searching for bikes on which I will ride mostly on roads, but also on terrains/mountains occasionally. After doing a few researches online, I finally decided to buy a hybrid bike.

Mostly people are suggesting to buy a Hybrid Bike which doesn't have suspension and disc brakes (even I'm not worried about disc brakes). So I thought to buy a bike which has a suspension fork with lockout.

My question is, is it instead also possible to get a lockout mechanism from store to add to a suspension fork which doesn't have a lockout itself?

Comment: Yes it is possible but it will probably work out more expensive than buying a bike with the appropriate spec. The cost of parts bought separately is generally quite a lot more than when they're bought as part of the "bike package"

Comment: Is the hybrid a 700c or 26inch wheeled variant? The market for high performance 700c suspension forks is very limited. If a LO suspension fork is a must - then I would be looking at the smaller wheeled hybrid as the fork choice is huge.

Comment: @OraNob [this](http://www.bsahercules.com/index.php?option=com_hikashop&ctrl=product&task=show&cid=102&name=neo&Itemid=183) is the one.

Comment: Personally, I would go with a rigid fork on that bike. That is a very low-end fork. It will also be heavy and flex a fair amount. A rigid fork will sharpen the steering up and keep the weight down. Additionally, I would put a question mark over the robustness of the suspension fork.

Comment: @OraNob It has an option to choose the fork. So probably I'll choose rigid over suspension.

Comment: I have hypothesized that one might "lock out" a front suspension by taking pieces of plastic plumbing pipe of an appropriate diameter and length, cutting out one side so they slip over the suspension cylinder pistons, and securing them with Velcro or some such.  Never tried it, though, or even looked closely at a suspension fork to see how plausible it is.

Comment: @OraNob -700C is 29", and there a lots of high performance 29" forks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't count on it, no. Low-end and touring forks may not have the parts available at all. With medium-to-high end MTB forks, the parts may be available but it often requires exchanging most of the innards, making it a much too costly proposition. It in not just a matter of adding a lever to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very rare, you'd better buy your bike already with that - maybe have a deal in your local shop to swap the fork to a lockout one when buying the bike.
Disc brakes are much better than rims IMHO

Comment: Cheap disc brakes are often much more expensive than mid-end V-brakes and often stop much worse. Though I agree that most forks can't add a lockout without you designing one on your own.

Comment: Cheap discs are worse than the cheapest V brakes, its likely the bike the OP is talking about has the cheapest discs available. Any V brake can be upgraded by installing better pads.  OP should go for V brakes (Unless my presumptions about price point of bike he is looking at is wrong).